# Whats the most efficient way to get the middle elements of a list?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I want to get a list but the last and the first elements. What is the most efficient way?

```
middle = init . tail
```

or:

```
middle = tail . init
```

And in the case of drop the n-first elements and the n-last elements?

Comment: Benchmark it? But I'd be surprised if you found a measurable difference.

Comment: I didn't profile it, because I sure there is no measurable difference, but I think it should be a "logical" difference and I'm curious

Comment: You *should* see a measurable difference on small lists, e.g. I would expect the second form to take 33% longer on lists of length 3. That would confirm my analysis below.

Comment: Right, but the difference will only be measurable if the total time is measurable. 133% of practically instantaneous is still practically instantaneous.

Comment: [`Data.Sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html) is likely to be faster than anything you can do with a list, at least in sufficiently large cases :)

Comment: @Zopa the standard method is to repeat the function call N times, and then divide by N to get the time per call.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Ah. You're right, of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't matter (much) either way. Note that `tail` is O(1) whereas `init` is O(n). If you take the `tail` first then `init` has to examine (n-1) constructors, for a total of n constructors examined.

If you take the `init` first then `init` examines n constructors and `tail` examines 1, for a total of n+1 constructors examined.

So it's every so slightly more efficient to do `init . tail`, but not so much more efficient that you should worry about it.

The same applies to dropping the first k elements from the front and end of the list, except that it might make more of a difference. If you drop the initial elements first, then they don't have to be examined when dropping the final elements, and you save a bit of time, so you should do

```
dropLast k . drop k
```

which examines n constructors, rather than

```
drop k . dropLast k
```

which examines n+k constructors.

Answer (score 4):

Both are effectively same. You are trying to optimize in the wrong position. If your code really need to do that kind of optimization then probably you don't require list, use something like Data.Sequence or Data.Vector.

Comment: Data.Sequence might be best here.